# Reading nodes in XML

Tags: xml, apache-flex

```
> <root>
> 
> <module c_name="Executive Library">
> <node cd_title="Document One"
> cd_link="http://localhost/userMana/upload/feature.xml"/>
> </module> <module c_name="Rate Card"/>
> 
> <module c_name="Time Sheet"> <node
> cd_title="Document Two"
> cd_link="http://localhost/userMana/upload/epl-v10.html"/>
> </module> </root>

<mx:Tree dataProvider="{tree.module}" labelField="@c_name" borderThickness="0" x="28" y="56" width="350" height="414"></mx:Tree>
```

I am able to read the module name, but how can i read the cd_title, when the label field is different.

Answer (score 1):

```
var yourXML:XML = yourXMLData;

for each(var x:XML in yourXML.module)
{
    trace(x.node.@cd_title);
}
```

havent tested it but it should work. You may want to build an ArrayCollection formatted for the Tree then set that as the dataprovider

Check these links: [accessing XML](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/accessing_xml_data/#section2), [using xml as dataprovider](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/201/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Book_Parts&file=about_dataproviders_057_16.html)